# How can Wikipedia Creative Commons images be attributed in video?

Tags: copyright, licensing, attribution

I have wondered this for a while but have not been able to find sufficient information about it.

Most media on Wikipedia is listed under the Creative Commons license. This means that it's free but must be given attribution when used (credited).

Here is a good example of that: [Reykjavík_Old_Harbor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7qGt.jpg)

[image]

Now, it is very easy to include attribution on a website, on print, etc, as a text credit can be placed above, below, alongside the image, etc.

But what about video? If you create a video for a corporate presentation, a tradeshow, a commercial, etc, how can you attribute this? Do you need to place a watermark throughout the video when the image is displayed, for example?

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

A watermark would be one acceptable means, but not the only one. If it was on YouTube you could put the attribution in the title of the work. In a presentation, you could make attribution part of the script of the presentation.

Comment: Or there’s the time honoured way of putting credits at the end

Answer (score 1):

## It's obvious that you use credits

### (ever watched a movie before?)

The following are examples of how you can do this.

- Credits before or after the video
- Credits when the image itself appears
- Credits in video description
- Link to a document in the video description with all sources